# I'm not getting any output after I have inserted data by default constructor but I'm not sure why not

Tags: c++, oop

So I am using default constructor to insert individual entries into memory and then read them by calling `getBookInfo()` method. When I try just to do a test run with only one variable I am not getting anything there even if I am calling `getBookInfo()` after I inserted the data.

Why is that?

Main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

#include "Book.h"

void main()
{
    Book book;

    book.setTitle("Advanced C++ Programming");
    book.setAuthorName("Linda", "Smith");
    book.setPublisher("Microsoft Press", "One Microsoft Way", "Redmond");
    book.setPrice(49.99);
    book.getBookInfo(); // <-= this should be output

    int i;
    cin >> i;
};
```

Book.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
using namespace std;

#include "Book.h"

Book::Book()
{
}

void Book::setTitle(string  title)
{
    title = title;
}


void Book::setPrice(double price)
{
    price = price;
}

string Book::convertDoubleToString(double number)
{
    return static_cast<ostringstream*>( &(ostringstream() << number) ) -> str();
}

// this should be output
string Book::getBookInfo()
{
    stringstream ss;
    ss << title << endl << convertDoubleToString(price) << endl;

    return ss.str();
}
```

Comment: why are you using same variables names?

Comment: Hint: don't use the same name for member variables and function parameters.

Comment: I would think so too, I'm just following class diagram which I was provided with my homework assignment. :)

Comment: I also don't see any output operations in your code.

Comment: `book.getBookInfo();` points to method on the bottom of book.cpp file.

Comment: I know, and my point still stands :) See Tod's answer.

Comment: If you don't want to change the names, use the this-pointer in your constructor/setters like so: this->price = price;

Comment: @jork, your right! :D I thought return would already be printed out... Dumb me lol

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to capture the data returned from getBootInfo(), for example

```
string result = book.GetBookInfo();
cout << result;
```

Answer (score 3):

Change

```
void Book::setTitle(string  title)
{
    title = title;
}
```

to

```
void Book::setTitle(string  title)
{
    this->title = title;
}
```

and the same change wherever this kind of code occurs. As written, the code assigns the value of the argument `title` to the argument `title`, i.e. it does nothing. The compiler probably warned you about this.

Or, as @hmjd said, change the names of the arguments.

Comment: There was no warnings and I tried adding `this->` and still no output. :(

Comment: Well, no output is a different matter. Where does the program do any output? `<g>`

Comment: As for clarification reasons... By saying arguments you mean the variables?

Comment: By "arguments" I mean the names used for the arguments to the function: in `void Book::setTitle(string title)`, `title` is the name of an argument of type `string`. The members of the class are "data members".

Comment: @Pete Becker: Thanks for explanation. I would change them if teacher wouldn't be so tight about following the class diagram. I understand your point though and thank you.